# Simplify "all or nothing" boolean expression

Tags: boolean-logic

Can a "all or nothing" boolean expression be simplified? Suppose I have three values, A, B, C, and want to determine if all three are true, or all three are false. Like a XOR gate, but with N values.

Can this statement be simplified?

`(A && B && C) || !(A || B || C)`

Comment: I guess that depends on what your definition of "simpler" is. I don't see how you're going to get out of referencing each value twice though, whether in a series of XOR operations or as you've done it here. If you allow for representing the values in a bitfield, then you could get away with a single bitwise XOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All true or all false basically means that all should be the same. So if the equality comparison is acceptable you can do this:

```
A == B && B == C
```

Comment: Good insight. I forget that you can compare boolean values to one another.